Proof verfication $\limsup x_n \le x_{n_1} + \epsilon$
Proof Attempt for the following statement:

Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers, show that $\forall \epsilon >0, \forall N \in N$, there exists $n_1 \ge N$, such that $\limsup x_n \le x_{n_1} + \epsilon$.

Attempt:
Since limsup is the lowest upper bound in regards to all tails $\{x_k ; k \ge n \text{ for any } n \}$ know that in each such tail there is one $x_v$ such that d($x_v, \limsup x_n$) < $\epsilon$  for any $\epsilon$. Hence for every $\forall \epsilon >0, \forall N \in N$ find $n_1 \ge N$, such that $\limsup x_n \le x_{n_1} + \epsilon$ since every tail has such a element. Is this true ? (Note I explictly try to avoid arguing by way of saying that there is a subsequence that converges to limsup)

MathJax tip: to get the "blackboard" style characters, such as $\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{Q}, \Bbb{Z}$, etc, use the command \mathbb{} or \Bbb{}. For example, $\forall N \in \Bbb{N}$ produces $\forall N \in \Bbb{N}$. (I bring it up because $\forall N \in N$ seems like you are quantifying over all sets that contain themselves, and Bertrand Russel would disapprove.)
